# useEffect and useState to fetch API data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use `useEffect`(on mount) to fetch from API and store it in `useState`. Fetch API is used to get the data. The problem is when initial page loading and also when I reload the page, it outputs an error called `test.map is not a function`. Why this happening and how to avoid this ?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
function App() {

  const[test, setTest] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    testfunc()
  }, [])

  async function testfunc(){
      let api = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      let apijson = await api.json()
      setTest(apijson)
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        test.map((item) => {
          return(
            <div>
              {item.name}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It is because `.map` is an array method and you are declaring the `test` state as an object. So you must change it to `useState([])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change {} to array first to be able to map over it. You can easily place `?` after test like this. or make in the default value of the state a default value for item name. because this error results as you map over an empty object.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
function App() {

  const[test, setTest] = useState([{name:"default"}])
  useEffect(() => {
    testfunc()
  }, [])

  async function testfunc(){
      let api = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      let apijson = await api.json()
      setTest(apijson)
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        test?.map((item) => {
          return(
            <div>
              {item.name}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you. Can you explain why I need `test?` ? It worked fine only changing `useState([])`.

Comment: The question mark is a condition if the array is empty or undefined. In case you removed the [] from useState([]). So this sets no default. So test?.map will not run into an error because it will not call the map function if test is undefined yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't map on an object `{}`, so you should need to define an array `[]` for the base state :

`const[test, setTest] = useState([])`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can't use the **.map** for objects.
Instead of this, you can make something like that

```
Object.keys(test).map(key => {
      const currentSmth = test[key]
      return(
        <div>
          {currentSmth.name}
        </div>
      )
    })
})
```

I think it helps you to solve your problem.
Be careful using the correct data structures and methods.